# How to install MySQL DB 5.6.12 (downloaded from mysql.com) on Xubuntu (kubuntu-desktop) 13.04?

Tags: installation, kubuntu, mysql

I have an experience of setting up and running MySQL on Windows. It is really easy. I just downloaded `.zip`, unpacked it in `C:\MySQL`, placed `C:\MySQL\bin` to PATH and then ran the server with the command:

```
C:\> mysqld --console
```

All the databases were stored in `C:\MySQL\data` folder.

And I want to do the same on Xubuntu 13.04 (but kubuntu-desktop). But I don't understand how. Linux version of MySQL is different.

Here are my steps:

I downloaded MySQL Community Server from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/. So I got this file: `MySQL-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm-bundle.tar`

Then I unpacked it to `/opt/mysql`.

And instead of `/bin` directory I got 7 files there. And I don't know what to do with them now:

```
path: /opt/MySQL-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm-bundle/

MySQL-client-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm
MySQL-devel-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm
MySQL-embedded-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm
MySQL-server-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm
MySQL-shared-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm
MySQL-shared-compat-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm
MySQL-test-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm
```

I suspect that `MySQL-server-5.7.1_m11-4.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm` is the MySQL DB server as I ran on Windows. But how to install it? How to run it? I don't want MySQL server to start automaticly on system boot. I want to start it manually as I did on Windows.

What do I need to do to install MySQL the same way I used it on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the .deb file, and not .rpm.  [Download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads) your desired architecture, either 32bit or 64bit.  Once done, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the download folder (probably the Downloads Folder), and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>.deb
```